# All $11$ Other Forms for the Chudnovsky Algorithm

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, pi, modular-forms

*Continued from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001509/generalizing-ramanujans-pi-formulas/2025312?noredirect=1#comment4158043_2025312)*

Ramanujan found this handy formula for $\pi$$$\frac 1\pi=\frac {\sqrt8}{99^2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}k\binom{2k}k\binom{4k}{2k}\frac {26390k+1103}{396^{4k}}\tag1$$

Which is related to Heegner numbers.

Sometime after, the Chudnovsky brothers came up with another $\pi$ formula$$\frac 1\pi=\frac{12}{(640320)^{3/2}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty
(-1)^k\frac {(6k)!}{(k!)^3(3k)!}\frac {545140134k+13591409}{640320^{3k}}\tag2$$
And according to Tito, $(2)$ has a total of $11$ other forms with integer denominators.

> **Question:** What are all $11$ forms? And what $e$-transcendal number to they correspond to?

Comment: You may like [this](http://maths.nju.edu.cn/~zwsun/ConjSeries.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chudnovsky-type pi formulas use the *j-function* $j(\tau)$ as the denominator. For $\tau=\frac{1+\sqrt{-d}}{2}$ and $\tau = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-d}$,  there are exactly 9+4=13 discriminants $d$ such that  $j(\tau)$ is an integer. (However, two of these do not yield series that converge.)

The j-function can easily be calculated in [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%5B12%5E3KleinInvariantJ%5B(1%2BSqrt%5B-163%5D)%2F2%5D,100%5D) as, for example

> N[12^3KleinInvariantJ[(1+Sqrt[-163])/2],100]

For convenience, given the well-known [sequence](https://oeis.org/A001421) defined in three equivalent ways,
$$h_k = \frac{(6k)!}{(3k)!\,k!^3}=\tbinom{2k}k\tbinom{3k}k\tbinom{6k}{3k}=\frac{12^{3k}\,\big(\tfrac{1}{2})_k\,\big(\tfrac{1}{6})_k\,\big(\tfrac{5}{6})_k}{k!^3}=1, 120, 83160, 81681600,\dots$$
with *factorial* $n!$, *binomial coefficient* $\binom nk$, and *Pochhammer symbol* $(a)_n$.

> **I.** $\tau=\frac{1+\sqrt{-d}}{2}$

$$\begin{aligned}
1/π &= 3\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\, h_k\, \frac{\color{blue}{7}\cdot 9k+8}{(15^3)^{k+1/2}}\\
1/π &= 4 \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\, h_k\, \frac{\color{blue}{11}\cdot  14k+15}{(32^3)^{k+1/2}}\\
1/π &= 12 \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\, h_k\, \frac{\color{blue}{19}\cdot  18k+25}{(96^3)^{k+1/2}}\\
1/π &= \frac{4}{3} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\, h_k\, \frac{\color{red}{27}\cdot506k+837}{(3\cdot160^3)^{k+1/2}}\\ 
1/π &= 12 \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\, h_k\, \frac{\color{blue}{43}\cdot 378 k+789}{(960^3)^{k+1/2}}\\
1/π &= 12 \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\, h_k\, \frac{\color{blue}{67}\cdot3906 k+10177}{(5280^3)^{k+1/2}}\\
1/π &= 12 \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\, h_k\, \frac{\color{blue}{163}\cdot3344418 k+13591409}{(640320^3)^{k+1/2}}\end{aligned}$$

> **II.** $\tau = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-d}$

$$\begin{aligned}
1/π &= 2\sum_{k=0}^\infty  h_k\, \frac{\color{blue}{8}\cdot 14k+12}{(20^3)^{k+1/2}}\\
1/π &= \frac{3}{2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty  h_k\, \frac{\color{red}{12}\cdot  44k+48}{(2\cdot30^3)^{k+1/2}}\\
1/π &= \frac{3}{\sqrt2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty  h_k\, \frac{\color{red}{16}\cdot  63k+80}{(66^3)^{k+1/2}}\\
1/π &= \frac{3}{2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty  h_k\, \frac{\color{red}{28}\cdot513k+864}{(255^3)^{k+1/2}}\end{aligned}$$

with [fundamental](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClassNumber.html) $d=3, 4, 7, 8, 11, 19, 43, 67, 163$ in blue and non-fundamental $d=12,16,27,28$ in red. However, the two smallest, namely $d=3,4,$ do not yield series that converges.

Comment: Just wondering, but is there a quick way to calculate $e^{\pi\sqrt{d}}$ for any number $d$ that involves the q-series and j-functions? And $d$ doesn't *have* to be a Heegner number, it can also be $58$ or $22$. (Both discovered by Ramanujan I think)

Comment: @Frank: Yes, the j-function input for WA and Mathematica is the same.

Comment: @Frank: I don't understand your first question. Can you clarify?

Comment: How would you calculate $e^{\pi\sqrt{67}}$ using the j-functions? How about $e^{\pi\sqrt{58}}$? Wikipedia describes a procedure for *only* Heegner numbers. So it'll work in calculating $e^{\pi\sqrt{67}}$. But not $e^{\pi\sqrt{58}}$ since $d=58$ is not a Heegner number.

Comment: @Frank: There is something wrong with your question. This post is about a pi formula using the jfunction. You want a formula for $e^{\pi\sqrt{67}}$ using the jfunction, is that it? What for?

Comment: Yeah... use that handy $j(q)=\frac 1q+744+196884q+\ldots$ And find an almost exact approximation for $e^{\pi\sqrt{67}}$. But how would you do that for $e^{\pi\sqrt{58}}$? The wikipedia link is https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number

Comment: @Frank: Look up Ramanujan-Sato series in Wiki. The j-function is **Level 1**. For $d=58$, you need the **Level 2** function $j_2(q) = \tfrac{1}{q} + 104 + 4372q + 96256q^2 + 1240002q^3 + \dots$

Comment: Oh god... Any other resources of SE posts you would recommend for reading?

Comment: @Frank: I wrote most of that Wikipedia article. I thought it was clear enough. :)  The number of such functions, if carefully defined and restricted, is ...  drumroll please... $163$. Fascinating it had to be that number, huh? This result is by Conway, Norton, and Atkin.  I wrote a short article about it, [_The 163 Dimensions of the Moonshine Functions_](https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0022).

Comment: *You* wrote most of that Wikipedia article?? That's *awesome*! Also, while reading about your article for Pi formulas, the command x = NSolve[Sum[h4(An+B)/Cn /. A →(3/2)√2  /. C→ -29 /. h4 → (2n)!3 / n!6, {n, 0, 50}] = 1/Pi, B, 30] doesn't work for me. Mathematica says the whole thing is "protected". Whatever that means. :/

Comment: @Frank: To label a variable with some value, use **one** equal sign, like a=1/Pi. To solve equations, use ***two*** equal signs like NSolve[x^2-x-1==0,x,100]. You **have** to read the instruction book.  :/

Comment: But either way, when I try, it gives a multitude of error. It says "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve", "$\left\{A\rightarrow\frac {3}{\sqrt{2}}\right\}$ is neither a list of replacement rules, nor a valid dispatch table..." and on and on... I also don't think you can use $C$ as an assigned variable. Sorry if this is bothering you...

Comment: @Frank: I will answer interesting BIG questions, but little details like Mathematica code you will have to figure out for yourself, agreed? :)   I do have other things to attend to. Just have patience. You just bought Mathematica. You'll get the hang of it in a few weeks -- or months.  :)

Comment: Okay, sure. **Actual question this time:** Has anyone found Ramanujan-type formulas for $\frac {1}{\pi^5}$ yet, how about $\frac 1{\pi^6}$ and $\frac 1{\pi^7}$. I read that people had previously found equations for lower degrees in one of your articles, but no one had found one for $\frac 1{\pi^5}$ (Congrats for reaching $19$K. I still have a long way to go. :/ )

Comment: @Frank: As pointed out in p.9 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.1332.pdf) by Zudilim, by taking powers of Ramanujan-type formulas for $1/\pi$, one can find $1/\pi^k$ for any $k>1$. However, the challenge is in finding $1/\pi^k$ that is ***not*** derived from lower powers.

Comment: @Frank Your Mathematica error about replacement rule is caused by using a right arrow character instead of -> even though they look the same.